# Entity Framework database first foreign key constraints on Delete

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-database-first

I'm trying to understand On Delete and On Update foreign key functions in Entity Framework.

I have a database first (sqlite) model consisting of two tables:

**Control**

ID

Name

ControlTypeID

and

**ControlType**

ID

Name

The foreign key constraints on ControlTypeID are set to "On Delete Set Default" and "On Update Cascade." Default is set to "1" on ControlTypeID

The tables are bound to a datagridview. When I delete a ControlType (say, ID=2) rather than Control.ControlTypeID being set to 1, it is set to null.

Does entity framework not preserve the database foreign key constraint rules when  it constructs the entity model?